# How to recombine values after a split in R?

Tags: r, split, lapply

I have a data variable X that I have done the following to

```
Xnew = split(X$col1,list(X$col3,X$col4))
S = sapply(Xnew,mean)
```

I now have a vector where each element can be accessed by

```
S['SomeValCol3.SomeValCol4']
```

Now I would like to create a vector containing columns equal to the number of unique values in col3 and where col4 is added as a column vector indexing each value. That is,

Col4    | Col3[1]| Col3[2] |....
Col4[0]| S['SomeValCol3.SomeValCol4'] | ...
.
.
.

And so on.

As an example lets say I have the following vector

```
S['v31.v41'] = 0.5
S['v32.v41'] = 0.25
S['v33.v41'] = 0.35
S['v31.v42'] = 0.5
S['v32.v42'] = 0.25
S['v33.v42'] = 0.35
S['v31.v43'] = 0.5
S['v32.v43'] = 0.25
S['v33.v43'] = 0.35
```

which I got from the split and then I want this matrix

```
V4 | V31 | V32 | V33
V41  0.5   0.25  035
V42  0.5   0.25  035
V43  0.5   0.25  035
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: `matrix(S, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE, dimnames = list(paste0("V", 41:43), paste0("V", 31:33)))` will give you the matrix you want. There's probably a more direct way using your original data though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `base R`

```
 xtabs(values~V1+V2, transform(stack(S), V2=sub('\\..*', '', ind),
                  V1=sub('.*\\.', '', ind)))
 #        V2
 #V1    v31  v32  v33
 # v41 0.50 0.25 0.35
 # v42 0.50 0.25 0.35
 # v43 0.50 0.25 0.35
```

#### data

```
 S <- structure(c(0.5, 0.25, 0.35, 0.5, 0.25, 0.35, 0.5, 0.25, 0.35
 ), .Names = c("v31.v41", "v32.v41", "v33.v41", "v31.v42", "v32.v42", 
 "v33.v42", "v31.v43", "v32.v43", "v33.v43"))
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Question, how do I access the individual elements?

Comment: @ReedRichards  You can use the row/column index to access the elements.   Suppose, if `res <- xtabs(values....);  res[1,1]#[1] 0.5`

Answer (score 1):

Using *reshape2* library I'd first *melt* vector S to a data.frame and add row/column variable names

```
library(reshape2)
S.melted <- melt(S)
S.melted$v1 <- gsub('\\.v[[:digit:]]+', '', rownames(S.melted))
S.melted$v2 <- gsub('\\v[[:digit:]]+\\.', '', rownames(S.melted))
```

which gives me S.melted in format as below:

```
        value v1  v2
v31.v41  0.50 v31 v41
v32.v41  0.25 v32 v41
...
```

and then obtain preferred format using *acast*

```
> acast(S.melted, v1 ~ v2)
    v41  v42  v43
v31 0.50 0.50 0.50
v32 0.25 0.25 0.25
v33 0.35 0.35 0.35
```

Comment: Maybe the example is not so clear but v31.v41, for example, are a concatenation of v31 and v41. Where v31 in my data could be a string like 'xfwfsefg', that is, there is no pattern like  '\\.v[[:digit:]]+'. Sorry about that.